# What happened at the end of the Magical Warfare's anime? Is Kazuma a Gekkou?

Tags: magical-warfare

In episode 12 of *Magical Warfare*, there was a lot left as a cliffhanger.

Since the show is not getting a season 2, I was wondering if anyone could explain what happened? Is Kazuma a Gekkou?

Comment: [it's adapted from a novel](http://myanimelist.net/manga/55431/Mahou_Sensou), so you could start reading that to find out the rest of the story

Comment: The ending made no sense to me, so I won't even try to answer. I will note that the picture Kazuma had of Kurumi was the same one Takeshi kept in his pocket, so maybe Kazuma is actually Takeshi. There are some other hints towards this as well, but I'd be lying if I said I understood anything towards the end of this series, so reading the novels is probably the only way to go.